# Maximum Occurence of a row in Oracle Database in Python

Tags: python, oracle

My **Oracle Database** contains values:-

```
PICTURE_ID  USER_ID
     101    1
     101    2
     102    1
     102    2
     102    3
     104    1
     104    2
     104    3
     104    3
```

I want to query over my database and get the result for a particular picture id with user_id with maximum occurrences.
Like for PICTURE_ID = 104 result should be like:-

```
User_ID
   3
```

As 3 occur maximum time.

Comment: Oracle is not MySQL, don't spam tags.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry my mistake.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks man. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT stats_mode(USER_ID) FROM LIKES WHERE PICTURE_ID=104.

**stats_mode()** get the value for the maximum occurrence of a value.

RESULT:-

```
STATS_MODE(USER_ID)
        3
```